# Page component will overlap when I re-size my browser

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I have the following components inside my web page ; a calendar and a date picker:-
[image]

And I set the layout for the calendar an the date picker as follow:-

```
.calender
{
 Width:75% !important;

    }

#datepicker{

position:absolute;
right:5%;
top:5%;
}
```

Now If the browser is maximize the layout will be fine , but  when I re-size my browser the date picker and the calendar will overlay as follow:-
[image]

So can anyone advice how to solve this layout problem, so the calendar and the date picket do not overlap ?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could do a:

```
clear:both;
```

If the calendar wasn't positioned absolute, other than that - you can use media queries to adjust the percentage of the calendar to a number higher so that it doesn't overlap.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries is a good article to learn about media queries.

Comment: i use the following @media (max-width: 500px) {
#datepicker{
clear:both
}
}
but it did not solve the overlap problem

Answer (score 1):

if you want them at the position and don't want them to top bottom i mean calendar first and below it the datepicker then try setting `min-width` and an `overflow:scroll` of the parent control.

Rest you can modify the css as

```
.calender
{
 Width:75% !important;
position: relative;
float:left;
    }

#datepicker{
position:relative;
float : right;
right:5%;
top:5%;
}
```

give a try if you can fiddle out the demo then please do :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but applying position:relative;
float : right;. will move the calender to the bottom of the page.

Comment: can you give a fiddle or something as to try it out. :) Try display table-cell for the two classes. tbale cell expands and contracts with the width of the page . Might work.

Comment: can you explain more , what do u mean by using table-cell for the two classes?

Comment: try providing a min width for the parent container. it will not resize after a particular width. min width might be equal to the min width of both the calendar and date picker